# How to call the function after UI loads? PyQt5

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, desktop

I'm building the desktop app. Before  `class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):` I have a section, that processes some initial data (code 1)

```
sample_directory_2 = []
sample_files_2 = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('./Processed'):
    filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
    sample_files_2.extend(filenames)
    break
the_dir = "Processed"
paths_2 = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(the_dir,filename)) for filename in os.listdir(the_dir) if not filename.startswith('.')]    

sample_directory_2.append(sample_files_2)
sample_directory_2.append(paths_2)

processed_info = []
for i in range(len(sample_directory_2[0])):
    file_info = []
    sample_file_2 = sample_directory_2[0][i]
    sample_path_2 = sample_directory_2[1][i]            
    sample_info_2 = pd.read_excel(ospath(sample_path_2), header = None, sheetname = 3)
    sample_info_2 = sample_info_2.iloc[0][0:3]
    file_info.append(sample_file_2)
    sample_info_2_list = numpy.array(sample_info_2).tolist() 
    file_info.extend(sample_info_2_list)
    processed_info.append(file_info)
```

After this section in `class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):` I have the code that creates QTableList and sets values to its items(code 2):

```
        self.clickSample_list.setRowCount(len(processed_info))
        self.clickSample_list.setColumnCount(len(processed_info[0]))

        labels = ['Имя', 'Массовые отклики', 'Процентранг', 'Валидность']
        self.clickSample_list.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

        for row in range(len(processed_info)):
            for column in range(len(processed_info[row])):
                self.clickSample_list.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(str(processed_info[row][column])))
```

Code 1 section takes pretty long time, and only after that, the UI begins to load.

I guess, what I need to do is: to make Code 1 a separate function and call it after UI loads. How to do that? Is there a command that calls the function after the loading of UI?

Answer (score -2):

I think what you probably need to do is place the Code 1 section in a separate function in your  class and call it at some event in the GUI.

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        #Initializing the UI
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.buttonName.clicked.connect(self.functionName)
    def functionName(self):
         ...
         #your code
         ...
```

Or if your Application restricts the use of this code outside the class then you can try calling it in the main function

```
from sys import argv, exit

def functionName():
    ...
    #code
    ....

    class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        ....

    def main():
            app = QApplication(argv)
            gui = Window()
            gui.show()
            functionName()
            exit(app.exec_())
```